# How do you take only the nth item in a text file?

Tags: python, flask, graph, slice

I have a text file:

```
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1
```

I am using Flask to launch a webserver where I am graphing the data. The data in positions 3, 6, 9, etc... needs to be one line of the graph.

Here is my attempt:

```
@cli.command()
def visualize():

   app = Flask(__name__)
   @app.route("/")
   def graph():
       with open('rundata.txt', "r") as values:
           values_sql = values[::3]
           return render_template('graph.html',  values=values_sql)
   app.run()
```

When I do not use [::3] line, it works, but it graphs every item in the text file. When I do use the [::3] line, the data does not even show up. Any clues as to why?

Comment: it's probably looking at every third line (since file objects can be iterated over as lines) -- you might try something like `values_sql = [int(x) for x in values.read().split(',')][::3]`

Comment: `values_sql = values[::3]` shouldn't even work because you're trying to slice a file object.

Comment: `list(values)[::3]` gives every third line (starting with the first) in Python3 but the `list(fileobj)` conversion is necessary -- I just assumed it worked without that in Python2.

Comment: @jedwards In Python 2 you'll probably get something like `file object has no attribute _getitem_`.